# django filter by current user to vote

Tags: python, django, view, django-queryset

I have a model:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    description = models.TextField()
    answers = models.ManyToManyField('Answer',related_name='answer_name', blank=True)
    post_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    vote = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

I am making a forum kind of thing where user can post question. What I want is if the question is useful then other user can vote the question but only once. If user has voted the question once and tries to vote again it show show message saying you cannot vote twice. I have written a view for this where everything works except the validation for voting twice.

Here is my view:

```
def VoteCountView(request, pk):

    ques = Question.objects.get(id=pk)
    cpk = ques.category.id
    valid_user = ques.user.username

    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        if request.user.is_general_user:
            if request.user.username == valid_user:
                messages.warning(request, "You cannot vote your own question")
                return redirect("question-detail", pk, cpk)
            else:
                vote_limit = Question.objects.values_list("vote", flat=True).filter(pk=pk).filter(user=request.user)[0]
                if vote_limit < 1:
                    vote_count = ques
                    count = vote_count.vote
                    count +=1
                    vote_count.vote = count
                    vote_count.user = request.user
                    vote_count.save()
                    return redirect("question-detail", pk, cpk)
                else:
                    messages.warning(request,"You cannot vote twice")
                    return redirect("question-detail", pk, cpk)
        else:
            messages.warning(request,"You are not allowed to vote a question")
            return redirect("question-detail", pk, cpk)
    else:
        messages.warning(request, "You must login/sign up to vote.")
        return redirect("question-detail", pk, cpk)
```

What I am trying to achieve here is `vote_limit = Question.objects.values_list("vote", flat=True).filter(pk=pk).filter(user=request.user)[0]`. I think my last filter what I am using `filter(user=request.user)` is not working  because its filtering by the user that has posted the question.

Can I do this by same model or I have to make different model to achieve this. Like:

```
class VoteCount(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    title = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    vote = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Can anyone help me ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use exists() for checking if a user has already cast a vote or not. I think u would need to create the model Votecount as you defined to accomplish the task. However vote can remain in question and not in Votecount model. Just update vote in Question model and add to Votecount model everytime a person votes up a answer.

```
def VoteCountView(request, pk): 
    ques = Question.objects.get(id=pk)
    cpk = ques.category.id
    valid_user = ques.user.username

    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        if request.user.is_general_user:
            if request.user.username == valid_user:
                messages.warning(request, "You cannot vote your own question")
                return redirect("question-detail", pk, cpk)
            elif VoteCount.objects.filter(user=request.user, title=ques).exists():
                messages.warning(request,"You cannot vote twice")
                return redirect("question-detail", pk, cpk)
            else:
                ques.vote +=1
                ques.save()
                v=Votecount(title=ques, user=request.user)
                v.save()    
        else:
            messages.warning(request,"You are not allowed to vote a question")
            return redirect("question-detail", pk, cpk)
    else:
        messages.warning(request, "You must login/sign up to vote.")
        return redirect("question-detail", pk, cpk)
```

Answer (score 3):

you could simply check

```
VoteCount.objects.filter(user=request.user, title=ques).exists()
```

to know if a user has already voted such question

Comment: yeah thats what I am asking... Should I make VoteCount model to achieve this or I can do this by Question model ???

Comment: I havent made VoteCount model. What I am asking is can I validate current user from Question model?? Or I have to make VoteCount model??

Comment: @Aaeronn yes because you need to memorize the actual user that made that vote